# How to add a line-break and a back reference in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, line-breaks, backreference

I'm trying to replace a string with another string and also add a line-break character, but I can't figure out the correct syntax. Here's a simplified example:

```
'first@second' -replace ('(fi.*t)@', "$1`n")
```

Result:

```
second
```

I then tried:

```
'first@second' -replace ('(fi.*t)@', '$1`n')
```

Result:

```
first`nsecond
```

It looks I can either have a line-break or a back-reference, but not both.
What do I need to change to get both?
What I want is:

```
first
second
```

Comment: No, you can have both. ``'first@second' -replace ('(fi.*t)@', "`$1`n")``. Or `'$1'+"`n"`

Comment: Terminology note: A [_backreference_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/backreference-constructs-in-regular-expressions) is a _pure regex feature_ for referencing a group that matched earlier _in the same regex_ (e.g, `\1`). While conceptually related, a [_capture-group substitution_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions#substituting-a-numbered-group) (e.g. `$1`) applies only to (regex-based) _string substitution_ operations.

Comment: An aside re syntax: The parentheses in `'...' -replace ('...', '...')` are unnecessary (this applies to all PowerShell operators with multiple RHS operands, such as `-split`).